# Is there vue devtools as ES module, or is there pinia prod ES module without dependencies?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, es6-modules, pinia

I try to use pinia 2.1.7 as ES module, together with Vue 3.3.8.

So:

```
<script type="module" src="./js/lib/vue-3.3.8.esm-browser.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="./js/lib/pinia-2.1.7.esm-browser.js"></script>
```

and:

```
import {defineComponent, createApp, nextTick} from "./lib/vue-3.3.8.esm-browser.js";
import {createPinia, setActivePinia} from "./lib/pinia-2.1.7.esm-browser.js"
```

and:

```
...
const pinia = createPinia();
setActivePinia(pinia);

const cntApp = createApp(App);
cntApp.use(pinia);
cntApp.mount('.vue-app');
...
```

So far this is clear to me.

I understand from the pinia ES module that it needs vue-demi and vue/devtools-api. So I additionally import vue-demi as an ES module which I take from the npm dist folder, but **I do not find the ES module for the devtools**.

I develop inside a CMS that is still best delivered with single pages, so I prefer to stay with ES import each page as long as possible, and not build one huge js package.

Questions:

- Is there a prod version of pinia without vue-demi and without api tools?
- Is there a possibility to include devtools as ES module or as script?

Comment: Please, clarify which packages cause problems and in which way.  There's https://unpkg.com/browse/@vue/devtools-api@6.5.1/lib/esm/ that may be in use, it's not bundled but this might not be a problem

Comment: Thank you very much @EstusFlask. I am now one step further and will clarify in an own answer.

Answer (score 1):

So if you are in the node universe and use npm, webpack or else, your scripts will be built with everything needed.

However if you have this project setup:

- You need to load single ES modules in browser
- You cannot use unpkg.com or else as the final code will be put into an hybrid mobile app
- You want to make sure that finally no unneeded code is included

then you have to pick and to adjust. I use Vue3 and Pinia and need to go with ES includes in the browser.

I suggest these steps:

1. Download the needed modules with npm as documented, e.g. `npm install pinia`, `npm install vue-demi`, `npm install vue/devtools-api` if needed. (If you are new to this: You can create a dummy npm lib folder and run `npm install` there, just to get all the packages.)
2. Copy the files needed in your project and load them in the browser as modules. For instance, I have now:

   ```
    <script type="module" src="./js/lib/vue-3.3.8.esm-browser.js"></script
    <script type="module" src="./js/lib/vue-devtools-6.5.1.esm/index.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="./js/lib/vue-demi-0.4.16.esm.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="./js/lib/pinia-2.1.7.esm-browser.js"></script>
   ```

You find those files in the packages, in the subfolders "dist" or "lib" or else. Except vue demi, which is explained next. For instance, my pinia file is here: `E:\Users\Peter...\Documents\.....\npmlib\node_modules\pinia\dist\pinia.esm-browser.js`

3. Vue demi is a simple script that basically imports and exports everything from Vue, and adds `set()` and `del()` to the interface, does some further changes to have compatibility to Vue3. Its index files in the package root need a package manager to run. But, in my case I use only Vue3, so I grab `/lib/v3/index.mjs`, alter the `import` statement so that the `from` statement finds a valid file, and store it as vue-demi-0.4.16.esm.js. That is now your own ES module.
4. As all those files are prepared for the package manager, you need to adjust the `from` part of the import statements. The browser must find a properly referenced file. See next.

If you read pinia.esm-browser.js, the many imported names at the begin are all from Vue.js but `set` and `del`. Only `set` and `del` are from vue-demi. So there is no "huge vue-demi script" you have to find, vue-demi just forwards all the imports from Vue.

So my pinia-2.1.7.esm-browser.js has now:

```
//import { hasInjectionContext, inject, toRaw, watch, unref, markRaw, effectScope, ref, isVue2, isRef, isReactive, set, getCurrentScope, onScopeDispose, getCurrentInstance, reactive, toRef, del, nextTick, computed, toRefs } from 'vue-demi';
import { hasInjectionContext, inject, toRaw, watch, unref, markRaw, effectScope, ref, isVue2, isRef, isReactive, set, getCurrentScope, onScopeDispose, getCurrentInstance, reactive, toRef, del, nextTick, computed, toRefs } from "./vue-demi-0.4.16.esm.js";

//import { setupDevtoolsPlugin } from '@vue/devtools-api';
import { setupDevtoolsPlugin } from "./vue-devtools-6.5.1.esm/index.js";
```

The vue-demi-0.4.16.esm.js looks like this:

```
import * as Vue from "./vue-3.3.8.esm-browser.js";

var isVue2 = false
var isVue3 = true
var Vue2 = undefined

... Everything else is unchanged ...

export * from "./vue-3.3.8.esm-browser.js";
export {
  Vue,
  Vue2,
  isVue2,
  isVue3,
  install,
}
```

It is all there, just grab and adjust it to the export statements.

You will find better ways to have flexibility with your import statements, to publish and to update. But, all this basically works.

---

**Edit 02.12.23**
After you have estimated the files needed, **do not change 3rd party code** just to make the import statements matching. As @Estus Flask points out in the comment, use the import map, it works fine. Like this:

```
<script type="importmap">
    {
        "imports":{
            "vue": "./js/lib/vue-3.3.8.esm-browser.js",
            "vue-demi": "./js/lib/vue-demi-0.4.16.esm.js",
            "@vue/devtools-api":"./js/lib/vue-devtools-6.5.1.esm/index.js"
        }
    }
</script>
```

Then, the 3rd party code will also find the files unchanged.

Note that the import map must stick to strict JSON syntax rules, in contrast to pure JavaScript. You cannot write e.g.

```
 imports: { ... }
```

It must be:

```
"imports":{ ... }
```

As JavaScript needs valid property names, while importmap needs valid JSON.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you edit third-party source code, which could not be necessary. <script type="importmap"> is the part you could be missing.

Comment: Editing third-party code is a no-go for any productive roll out. At least it makes the process slow and error prone. I tried the importmap a couple of days ago, it did not work, somehow I've read that Mozilla does not support it, but now I've tried again and it works fine. So this is the way to go. Thank you for pointing this out again :-)

Comment: importmap is a recent thing with poor browser support, and native ESM are barely usable without it. Sadly, we still have to use build tools to not jump through hoops in real work.